# Why Totem, EOG, ...? have dark toolbars with default gnome-shell theme - Adwaita?

Tags: 12.04, gtk3

Totem, EOG, have dark toolbars for some reason:

[image]

while other regular GTK3 applications have expected toolbar:

[image]

This doesn't look like preferred way, so why is it like this and how can I set all GTK3 applications to use uniform toolbars?

Comment: Same with gnome-mplayer, just searching for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into /usr/share/themes/Adwaita/gtk-3.0/ folder, there is a file gtk-dark.css. I have no idea why it is there, because I didn't installed the Adwaita dark theme. Also the Advanced Settings menu is showing me only the Adwaita theme, not possible to choose a dark one. So it seems that it isn't installed. From my point of view, this file makes no sense. But instead of deleting it, move it to gtk-dark.css.bak and reload the shell. This will fix the look of EOG, Totem and also Gnome MPlayer.

Comment: "I have no idea why it is there, because I didn't installed the Adwaita dark theme." It's a _variant_ of the Adwaita theme, so it's installed as part of it. In theory, themes can have any number of variants with any names, but in practice, light/dark is the main distinction, and Adwaita is the main example.

Answer (score 1):

That is for the applications which deals with pictures and videos to maximize the contrast between the application body and the media inside.

It's recommended to make the whole them to dark if you want a singleton theme. You can set this via gnome tweak tool!

Answer (score 0):

That's how the GNOME project made the theme since 3.2 and above. It does that to Movie Player, Image Viewer, Boxes and other apps. It has dark toolbars in GNOME Shell too, but I don't know why they didn't make it a separate theme instead of just putting it into one.

Comment: After moving this file, you have to reload the shell. Dark toolbars will go away.